# RELEASE build APK does not build correctly INTERMITANT

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, build, apk

Soo Im going to struggle to explain this problem... but basically the way I can tell that this is occurring is that when I release/build my android app one of the first things the application does is start a foreground task. Sometimes the application foreground task shows a generic ANDROID icon in place of where my apps logo would be. (please see image for example)
[image]

I don't know what it is/exact steps I do to eventually get apk to release correctly but this is usually done by me rebuilding/cleaning until the apk gets released successfully (i know its 'worked' only when  I see my logo instead of the generic android image in the foreground task)
Is there something I can do soo when I release/create .apk file the file is always released correctly/always fully refreshed?
I have never had this issue before and none of my code changes between having the issue and when the issue going away... the apk will literally at some point just build correctly after a clean or rebuild or both or sometimes up to 30 attempts of cleaning/rebuilding?